# If a website doesn't use HTTPS to do user log in, are the users passwords fairly unprotected?

Tags: https, passwords, security

This question tries to look into whether doing HTTPS log in is very important for any website.

Is it true that for many websites, if the login is done through HTTP but not HTTPS, then anybody can pretty much see the userID and password easily along the internet highway (or by looking between a router and the internet connection in an Internet Cafe)?

If so... do popular frameworks actually use HTTPS by default (or at least as an option), such as Rails 2.3.5 or Django, CakePHP, or .Net?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any machine on the pathway (that the packets pass through) can just examine the contents of the those packets. All it takes is a capturing proxy or a promiscuous mode network card with something like WireShark. Assuming that the passwords aren't encrypted in some other way (at a higher level), they will be visible.

I can't answer the second part of your question since I have no knowledge of those particular products but I would say that the inability to use secure sockets would pretty much make them useless.

Comment: While @paxdiablo is dead on, just any promiscuous mode network interface won't do. e.g. HTTP traffic is TCP traffic which is not broadcast traffic. This means that the traffic does not make unnecessary round-trips to machines that don't share the same collision domain. Most networks are built using switches where TCP traffic in these networks are routed to its intended destination. As long no switch along the way is malicious, you are presumably safe. Wireless networks are a different thing entierly, I would not sign on any service without encryption when using a wireless access point.

Answer (score 0):

Pax is right about passwords that aren't otherwise encrypted being visible.

Still, most sites don't use SSL still, and it does put the users at a certain degree of risk when accessing sites from public wifi.

HTTPS isn't a framework level option, it would be something you'd do when you set up the webserver. If you were to use an apache configuration for instance, you would open it up to a properly configured https, close http and install a certification. The framework wouldn't have a direct influence on that portion of the release.

Answer (score 0):

If the user credentials are submitted via an HTML webform without HTTPS, then it is unsecure, the data is submitted in plain text.  However, if the website uses HTTP authentication instead, then the server can send back a 401 reply (or 407 for proxies) to any request that does not provide valid credentials.  401/407 is the server's way to ask for credentials, and the reply provides a list of authentication schemes (Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, etc) that the server supports, which are usually more secure by themselves.  The client/browser sends the same request again with the necessariy credentials in one of the schemes, then the server either sends the requested data, or sends another 401/407 reply if the credentials are rejected.